# Android Widget adding buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to add buttons to my (working) widget, but it keeps getting poisoned (widget image fails to load).

This is my layout....what's wrong with it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/widget">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageButtonButton
        android:id="@+id/snooze"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_snooze_24dp">
    </ImageButtonButton>

    <ImageButtonButton
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp">
    </ImageButtonButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not `ImageButtonButton` it should be `ImageButton`